# AnkhSVN Pending Changes customization in vs2012

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2012, ankhsvn

I am wondering if anyone knows how to change the view columns in the pending changes window.  I am using Visual Studio 2012 Professional and AnkhSVN as the plugin. When I start-up VS, the default view columns (Path, Project, Change, and Full Path) are there. I would like to permanently add the Modified column to the window. Is there a way to configure the column options?